# AMPL shorter form

Tags: optimization, ampl

as I am not very familiar with AMPL, i defined some variables in a long way such as

```
   ....
   subject to price1:  price[11 ] = 14.03;
   subject to price2:  price[12 ] = 11.06;
   subject to price3:  price[13 ] = 8.50;
   ....
```

It would be great if i can define these constrains in a shorter way. such as

```
#.mode file
param price{t in 1..T};

#.dat file
param price:= 14.03 11.06 8.50;
```

But I couldnt make it work. I wonder if you guys have any idea.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify not only values for `price` but also corresponding keys because `price` is indexed over a set:

```
param price :=
 11 14.03
 12 11.06
 13 8.50;
```

Here's a complete example:

```
param T;
param price{t in 1..T};

data;

param T := 13;

param price :=
 11 14.03
 12 11.06
 13 8.50;
```